# AccessViolationException when editing an image

Tags: vb.net, image, memory, image-processing

This is the code I use (b is a bitmap):

```
 Private Class BitmapData
        Public Bitmap As Bitmap
        Public ByteData As Byte()
        Public BitmapData As Imaging.BitmapData

        Public Shared Function LockBits(ByVal b As Bitmap) As BitmapData

            LockBits = New BitmapData
            LockBits.Bitmap = b
            Dim bmpRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height)
            ReDim LockBits.ByteData(b.Width * b.Height * 4 - 1)

            LockBits.BitmapData = b.LockBits(bmpRect, Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, b.PixelFormat)
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(LockBits.BitmapData.Scan0, LockBits.ByteData, 0, LockBits.ByteData.Length)
        End Function
End class
```

When I run the code, a AccessViolationException appears.

What's wrong with the code, and how to fix it?

Comment: What's the AccessViolationException?  Attempted to read or write protected memory? or ?

Comment: Attempted to read or write protected memory.

Comment: You're dimensioning the `ByteData` array on the assumption of 4 bytes per pixel. Is it possible that your bitmap's `PixelFormat` is something other than that?

Comment: As much as I see - no.